# Nil Values are being recorded when a form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, null, updating

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer on here.

I recently created a date_regex validation method for validating dates

```
VALID_DATE_REGEX = /\d{2}[\/]\d{2}[\/]\d{4}/
```

I know the regex isn't good right now, and I'll update that later, but I don't need any help with that.

I added a field that lets users select their birthday. I had to update my users model to allow such functionality.

**Migrations File**

```
class AddAgeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :age, :integer
    add_column :users, :birthday, :date
    add_column :users, :location, :string
  end
end
```

Here is my validation in Users.rb

```
validates :birthday, format: { with: VALID_DATE_REGEX }, :on => :update
```

Trying to figure out what the problem was, I fired up Rails Console

```
u = User.find(1)
u.update_attributes(:birthday => '12/22/1992')
=> u.save (false)
u.errors.full_messages
=> Birthday is invalid
u.birthday
=> nil
```

It looks like the problem is I expected the value of birthday to be '12/22/1992' but instead it was nil.

I figured out that that was the reason why the record wasn't updated in the database. I don't know if it's a problem with the attribute being stored as a date, but it doesn't work.

**Users Controller**

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
    flash[:success] = "Your profile has been updated"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Users Edit Page**

```
<% @title = "Edit Profile" %>

<h2>Update your information here</h2>

  <div class = "center">

    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :name, 'Username', class: 'marker' %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p> 
      <%= f.label :email, class: 'marker' %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>

    <p> 
      <%= f.label :birthday, class: 'marker' %>
      <%= f.text_field :birthday %>
    </p>

    <p> 
      <%= f.label :location, class: 'marker' %>
      <%= f.text_field :location %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update">
    </p>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

Help is appreciated.

**Update**

I changed the birthday attribute to string type. Now, when I run update_attributes(:birthday) in the console, it saves, but when I type the same thing in the text box it doesn't save.

I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys, I finally figured it out. There were 2 problems, the first with my birthday attribute and the second with my users_params.

As mentioned earlier, I declared my birthday attribute as a date field. It works better if the attribute is of string type.

```
add_column :users, :birthday, :string
```

I then migrated the file and worked with Rails Console.

```
u = User.first
u.update_attributes(:birthday => "12-22-1992")
```

This time the value was recorded properly and saved.

```
u.birthday
=> "12-22-1992"
```

I then tested it out in my Rails app in my edit form.

The value was still invalid and I just found out why.

The problem was with my user_params method

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
 :location)
end
```

I simply added the :birthday attribute to my users_params and it fixed my problem. This time the birthday was successfully saved.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to save a string as a date object.

```
u.update_attributes(:birthday => DateTime.strptime("12/22/1992", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Should work as it will return a Date object that can then be saved into your database

EDIT:  As it has been mentioned

```
u.update_attribute(:birthday, DateTime.strptime("12/22/1992", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

update_attribute (sans 's') takes the parameters (name, value).  Also, this will skip validation.

```
u.update_attributes(:birthday => DateTime.strptime("12/22/1992", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

update_attributes takes the hash parameter.  Also, this will not skip validation.

Comment: You're getting close, only problem is that it doesn't match my current regex. The console stores the birthday result as "1992-12-22" while my regex requires it says "12-22-1992". Maybe there's another method for that?

Comment: `update_attribute` syntax would result in error => [Check syntax of update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute)

Comment: @DarkMouse try using "%Y-%m-%d"

Comment: @DarkMouse, validating the format of the date object isn't as necessary once you've turned it into a DateTime object.  You might be better off validating the user input *before* you turn it into a date object.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a `string` here `u.update_attribute(:birthday => '12/22/1992')`, not `date`. This is the reason of failing the `:update`. Check [#strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class) and find the formatting which pass your needs.

Try `u.update_attributes(:birthday, Date.strptime("12/22/1992", "%m/%d%Y"))`.

UPD

To make it save correctly (as you mentioned in comment) try

```
u.update_attributes(:birthday, Date.strptime("12/22/1992", "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: `u.update_attributes`/ `u.update_attribute` and NOT `u.update_attributed`

Comment: You missed another one in first line. :) Just for reference `u.update_attribute` skips model level validations so `u.update_attributes` would be preferable.

Comment: o, really? so using singular form we can update attribute with invalid data? did not know, thanks!

Comment: No problem. :) Check this out:[update_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) and do verify the `update_attribute` syntax  as your current one would surely result in error.